# Why is RStudio running a different version of R when I run as an admin?

Tags: r, unix, rstudio

When I call `sudo rstudio` in Terminal, it runs off of the CRAN R version, but if I just run `rstudio` it runs off of Microsoft R Open.

Why could this be?

Comment: What are the results of `which rstudio` vs. `sudo which rstudio`?

Comment: They're the same. `/usr/bin/rstudio`

Comment: What about `which R` vs `sudo which R`?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Anything in `~/.profile`?

Comment: xubuntu OS. in profile it has

`# BCE: Added by bootstrap
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin

# BCE: Added by bootstrap
export PATH=${HOME}/miniconda/bin:${PATH}

# YKP: Added by me
alias mro="/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/bin/R"
export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/lib64/microsoft-r/3.3/lib64/R/bin/R
`

among other things.